# In VSCode, JSHint warns about missing semicolons

Tags: javascript, visual-studio-code, jshint

I am working on a JavaScript project. Visual Studio Code is my IDE and I see warnings about missing semicolons at the end of lines. The warnings are generated by JSHint. Since having semicolons at the end of lines is optional, I want to get rid of these warnings.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

JSHint has an option that suppresses warnings about missing semicolons called `asi`. Open VSCode settings (<kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>,</kbd>), search `jshint options` and click on `Edit in settings.json`

[image]

Add the following to `settings.json`:

```
"jshint.options": {
    "asi": true
}
```

If you already have `"jsint.options"` in your `settings.json`, simply just add `"asi": true` inside it.

**Note:**

You can edit `settings.json` for `User` or `Workspace`. In the image, you see that `User` tab (indicated by a red 1) is selected. In this mode, any change in `settings.json` affects all VSCode projects. If you want to apply this change only on this project, first select `Workspace` tab (indicated by a red 2) and then click on `Edit in settings.json`.